# Code works in Management Studio but not in the Dataset of an .rdl report

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, rdl

Why does this only work in management studio and not in the dataset of a rdl report?

I don't have access to the live database so I cannot add this function directly into the database.

```
if OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.PreviousFriday', N'FN') is not null
    drop function dbo.PreviousFriday;
go
create function dbo.PreviousFriday (@Date datetime)
returns datetime
with execute as caller
as
begin
    declare @PreviousFriday datetime;

    set @PreviousFriday = DATEADD(DAY, (case DATEPART(DW, @Date)
        when 1 then -2
        when 2 then -3
        when 3 then -4
        when 4 then -5
        when 5 then -6
        when 6 then 0
        when 7 then -1
    end), @Date)
    return(@PreviousFriday);
end
go

if OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.NextFriday', N'FN') is not null
    drop function dbo.NextFriday;
go
create function dbo.NextFriday (@Date datetime)
returns datetime
with execute as caller
as
begin
    declare @NextFriday datetime;

    set @NextFriday = DATEADD(DAY, (case DATEPART(DW, @Date)
        when 1 then 5
        when 2 then 4
        when 3 then 3
        when 4 then 2
        when 5 then 1
        when 6 then 0
        when 7 then 6
    end), @Date)
    return(@NextFriday);
end
go
```

Here is the error I am getting:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the query in SSRS needs to be DML (Data Manipulation Language)

ie

```
 select * from ...
```

or

```
 exec dbo.prcGetMyData ...
```

That sort of thing...



But you are trying to enter **DDL** (Data Definition Language)  ie you're attempting to change the underlying database, which would be somewhat of a security issue if this were permissible.

you could just create a dataset called LastFriday with your script inside it.  You could then use the value of the dataset inside your textbox or where-ever...

```
SELECT    DATEADD(DAY, (CASE DATEPART(DW, @Date) 
                         WHEN 1 THEN - 2 
                         WHEN 2 THEN - 3 
                         WHEN 3 THEN - 4 
                         WHEN 4 THEN - 5 
                         WHEN 5 THEN - 6 
                         WHEN 6 THEN 0 
                         WHEN 7 THEN - 1 END), @Date) AS LastFriday
```

If you want to share that among multiple reports, create a shared dataset.  (you'll need to do the same for NextFriday!)

OR you could avoid TSQL entirely and just create the function as code inside your report.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I will need to bypass tsql